Laravel blade - show eager loaded relation values
I have two tables with a one toy many relation

category_type (e.g. a value of "Fruit"
category  (e.g. a value of "Apple"

I would like to build a dropdown with values like "Fruit - Apple".
In my controller I query both tables and send it to the view.
    public function edit(Pdlocation $pdlocation)
    {
        $categories = Category::with('CategoryType:name,id')
            ->get(["name", "category_type_id","id"]);

            return view('admin.pdlocation.edit',compact('pdlocation','categories'));
    }


In my blade I try to the the name from the category (Apple) but also the name from the referenced category type (Fruit)
    @foreach ($categories as $category)
    <ul>
        <li>{{ dump($category); }}
        <li>{{ dump($category->category_type); }}
        <li>{{ $category->name }}
        <li>{{ $category->category_type->name }}
    </ul>
    @endforeach

Unfortunately I get an error of Attempt to read property "name" on null for this command $category->category_type->name.
The dump($category) gives me this output
{
  "name": "Fruit",
  "category_type_id": 3,
  "id": 2,
  "category_type": {
    "name": "Apple",
    "id": 3
  }
}

The dump($category->category_type) gives me a NULL.
How can I get the value of $category->category_type->name?

dump($category) does not even print more than one related model. Can you please share your both migration files??

Also share your relationship defination defined in the model class


Make sure that the relationship method in the Category model is correctly named as "categoryType".
public function categoryType()
{
return $this->belongsTo(CategoryType::class, 'category_type_id');
}


with method in the query should use the relationship name as defined in the model. Like $categories = Category::with('categoryType')->get();

Check that the category_type_id field in the categories table correctly references the id field in the category_types table.


If you follow above steps and make sure the relationship is properly defined and loaded, you should be able to access the name property of the CategoryType like $category->categoryType->name.

Brilliant, thanks!
I used $category->category_type->name but to adress the relation it has to be the relation classname, in my case $category->categoryType->name
